# thread_local vs boost::thread_specific vs ::pthread_key_t

Tags: c++

I have a program that dlopens some libraries (all C++), that use TLS for a variable (which passed to all libraries). With the keyword 'thread_local' and with 'boost::thread_specific', the storage of the variable is different for every thread AND for every shared library. With 'pthread_key_t' it's only different for every thread, it behaves as expected. I guess 'boost::thread_specific' uses 'thread_local' and that's why it behaves like it. Why does 'thread_local' behave like this?

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

$ uname -a
Linux robert-y510p 3.13.0-49-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 24 19:29:48 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What do you mean "different for every shared library"?

Comment: It's like very shared library has its own thread storage, the thread storage is not shared.